# Random-Pivot Quicksort in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, monads, quicksort, referential-transparency

Is it possible to implement a quicksort in Haskell (with RANDOM-PIVOT) that still has a simple `Ord a => [a]->[a]` signature?

I'm starting to understand Monads, and, for now, I'm kind of interpreting monads as somethink like a 'command pattern', which works great for IO.

So, I understand that a function that returns a random number should actually return a monadic value like IO, because, otherwise, it would break referential transparency. I also understand that there should be no way to 'extract' the random integer from the returned monadic value, because, otherwise, it would, again, break referential transparency.

But yet, I still think that it should be possible to implement a 'pure' `[a]->[a]` quicksort function, even if it uses random pivot, because, it IS referential transparent. From my point of view, the random pivot is just a implementation detail, and shouldn't change the function's signature

OBS: I'm not actually interested in the specific quicksort problem (so, I don't want to sound rude but I'm not looking for *"use mergesort"* or *"random pivot doesn't increase performance in practice"* kind of answers) I'm actually interested in how to implement a 'pure' function that uses 'impure' functions inside it, in cases like quicksort, where I can assure that the function actually is a pure one.

Quicksort is just a good example.

Comment: If your random-pivot quicksort implementation has a bug that depends on the random pivots chosen, then it's not referentially transparent. So you have to be _really_ careful here. (This is independent of whether it's possible to hide impurity in Haskell.)

Comment: You can't escape from `IO`. If it uses an impure function, it's impure, period. Luckily, PRNG is possible without getting impure.

Comment: And how would you generate a random number with a pure function?

Comment: The only "right" way to do this in production code would be to pass in the seed explicitly and get a type of `RandGen -> [a] -> [a]` or the like. Which is not a bad thing! Reproducable random sequences for testing purposes can be a real boon, even if you didn't intially expect to need them.

Comment: @sclv: Also true. But this is nasty, since you always need to explicitly pass the seed. And your type-signature is suboptimal, since you can't use the random state afterwards. How about `([a] -> RandGen -> ([a],RandGen)`?

Comment: @FUZxxl -- arguably yes, but if you have a good splittable generator (which we try for, and always fall short of -:)) then you don't need to fret so much about threading. And in fact, in this case, I wouldn't be particularly troubled even by a relatively poor split.

Comment: Another point, which is somewhat unrelated, is that there's no advantage to random pivots over a deterministic but well-chosen sequence of pivots except in the ability to thwart an adversarial opponent. And, of course, I'd argue that in a situation where you are actually concerned about an adversarial sequence, then there's no earthly reason not to use mergesort or something else that is guaranteed not to blow up.

Comment: @sclv: Doesn't Plader actually sad, that he don't want answers in the style "try another way instead", but yes. AFAIK, the only advantage is for security, you can cause a O(n²) runtime with a prepared list if you know the pivots. But it's impossible if the pivot is randomly chosen.

Comment: One idea: you could hash the input list somehow to seed the random number generator.

Comment: @Dan: This isn't possible, as you know nothing about the list but that it's elements are comparable.

Comment: @FUZxxl true. I've implemented the technique, with the added assumption that the elements are also hashable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, where you know that the function is referentially transparent, but you can't proof it to the compiler, you may use the function `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` from the module `Data.Unsafe`.

For instance, you may use `unsafePerformIO` to get an initial random state and then do anything using just this state.

But please notice: Don't use it if it's not *really* needed. And even then, think twice about it. `unsafePerformIO` is somewhat the root of all evil, since it's consequences can be dramatical - anything is possible from coercing different types to crashing the RTS using this function.

Comment: As I always say, just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: You also have to be careful that it doesn't use the same random number every time, because the compiler memoises the result of the first call to "unsafePerformIO (whatever)" rather than generating a new random number for every call to "sort".  Hey, you said it was a pure function, right?

Comment: When I'm SURE I'm not breaking referential transparency (like this quicksort example), I think it's a good solution.

Comment: @Plader It's fully possible it won't work the way you want due to lambda lifting.  This is the point Paul Johnson was making.  Due to the details of quicksort, it probably won't be the case in this algorithm, but be aware that unsafePerformIO makes the compiler treat the expression as pure.  That means it can use any optimizations that would be valid with pure code, including evaluating it only once, and retaining that result for all further uses.

Comment: @Plader, Keep in mind that `unsafePerformIO` also ties you to a particular evaluation strategy.  So it may be perfectly fine if you intend to write *GHC* code, but it is completely ill-defined *Haskell* code.  For example, I'm working on a virtual machine for Haskell that does extremely aggressive runtime specialization.  Most of the usual `unsafePerformIO` hacks are completely, irreparably broken using this evaluation strategy.  Hereditary purity may be inconvenient at times, but it does have many advantages. Take that into account.

Answer (score 7):

You are making a false assumption that picking the pivot point is just an implementation detail.  Consider a partial ordering on a set.  Like a quicksort on cards where

card a < card b if the face value is less but if you were to evaluate booleans:

```
  4 spades < 4 hearts (false)
  4 hearts < 4 spades (false)
  4 hearts = 4 spades (false)
```

In that case the choice of pivots would determine the final ordering of the cards. In precisely the same way

for a function like

```
a = get random integer  
b = a + 3
print b
```

is determined by a.  If you are randomly choosing something then your computation is or could be non deterministic.

Comment: This is a terrific point.  Since quicksort isn't stable with random pivot choice, it's not actually referentially transparent when elements equal by the ordering can be distinguished by non-ordering means.

Comment: You're mainly right, but the Eq typeclass rules would require 4 hearts = 4 spades. Eq is for total orderings. Even then, one could distinguish :-)

Comment: OK, randomly choosing something can make your computation non-deterministic. BUT even in quicksort you can take extra care during 'partition' to ensure it's stable (i.e. deterministic even with random pivot)

Answer (score 4):

OK, check this out.

Select portions copied form the [hashable package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable), and voodoo magic language pragmas

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, NoMonomorphismRestriction, OverlappingInstances #-}

import System.Random (mkStdGen, next, split)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Bits (shiftL, xor)

class Hashable a where
    hash :: a -> Int

instance (Integral a) => Hashable a where
    hash = fromIntegral

instance Hashable Char where
    hash = fromEnum

instance (Hashable a) => Hashable [a] where
    hash = foldl' combine 0 . map hash

-- ask the authors of the hashable package about this if interested
combine h1 h2 = (h1 + h1 `shiftL` 5) `xor` h2
```

OK, so now we can take a list of anything `Hashable` and turn it into an `Int`. I've provided `Char` and `Integral a` instances here, more and better instances are in the hashable packge, which also allows salting and stuff.

This is all just so we can make a number generator.

```
genFromHashable = mkStdGen . hash
```

So now the fun part. Let's write a function that takes a random number generator, a comparator function, and a list. Then we'll sort the list by consulting the generator to select a pivot, and the comparator to partition the list.

```
qSortByGen _ _ [] = []
qSortByGen g f xs = qSortByGen g'' f l ++ mid ++ qSortByGen g''' f r
    where (l, mid, r) = partition (`f` pivot) xs
          pivot = xs !! (pivotLoc `mod` length xs)
          (pivotLoc, g') = next g
          (g'', g''') = split g'

partition f = foldl' step ([],[],[])
    where step (l,mid,r) x = case f x of
              LT -> (x:l,mid,r)
              EQ -> (l,x:mid,r)
              GT -> (l,mid,x:r)
```

**Library functions**: `next` grabs an `Int` from the generator, and produces a new generator. `split` forks the generator into two distinct generators.

**My functions**: `partition` uses `f :: a -> Ordering` to partition the list into three lists. If you know folds, it should be quite clear. (Note that it does not preserve the initial ordering of the elements in the sublists; it reverses them. Using a foldr could remedy this were it an issue.) `qSortByGen` works just like I said before: consult the generator for the pivot, partition the list, fork the generator for use in the two recursive calls, recursively sort the left and right sides, and concatenate it all together.

Convenience functions are easy to compose from here

```
qSortBy f xs = qSortByGen (genFromHashable xs) f xs
qSort = qSortBy compare
```

Notice the final function's signature.

```
ghci> :t qSort
qSort :: (Ord a, Hashable a) => [a] -> [a]
```

The type inside the list must implement both `Hashable` and `Ord`. There's the "pure" function you were asking for, with one logical added requirement. The more general functions are less restrictive in their requirements.

```
ghci> :t qSortBy
qSortBy :: (Hashable a) => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
ghci> :t qSortByGen
qSortByGen
  :: (System.Random.RandomGen t) =>
     t -> (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

**Final notes**

`qSort` will behave *exactly the same way* for all inputs. The "random" pivot selection is. in fact, *deterministic*. But it is obscured by hashing the list and then seeding a random number generator, making it "random" enough for me. ;)

`qSort` also only works for lists with length less than `maxBound :: Int`, which ghci tells me is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. I thought there would be an issue with negative indexes, but in my ad-hoc testing I haven't run into it yet.

---

Or, you can just live with the IO monad for "truer" randomness.

```
qSortIO xs = do g <- getStdGen -- add getStdGen to your imports
                return $ qSortByGen g compare xs


ghci> :t qSortIO
qSortIO :: (Ord a) => [a] -> IO [a]
ghci> qSortIO "Hello world"
" Hdellloorw"
ghci> qSort "Hello world"
" Hdellloorw"
```

Answer (score 2):

Haskell provides the [ST](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Control-Monad-ST.html) monad to perform non-referentially-transparent actions with a referentially transparent result.

Note that it doesn't *enforce* referential transparency; it just insures that potentially non-referentially-transparent temporary state can't leak out.  Nothing can prevent you from returning manipulated pure input data that was rearranged in a non-reproducible way.  Best is to implement the same thing in both ST and pure ways and use QuickCheck to compare them on random inputs.

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. As long as you don't use `unsafeIOToST`, a computation in `ST`, while it may be impure internally, can't reveal the fact that it was impure.  The type of `runST` is `(forall s. ST s a) -> a`, which expresses that fact: the `s` is the internal state, and `runST` can only run `ST` actions which don't depend on an initial state. The documentation for `ST` cites the paper *Lazy Functional State Threads*, whose abstract begins "Some algorithms make critical internal use of updatable state, *even though their external specification is purely functional*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: (Also, links.  The [documentation for `ST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html) is available on Hackage, as usual, and Google Scholar turns up plenty of results for *[Lazy Functional State Threads](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Lazy+Functional+State+Threads)*, including (I think) at least some that aren't behind a pay wall.)

Comment: Just out of interest; can you please tell me how random numbers are possible in ST? At a quick glance, I can't find any way to do this.

Comment: The ST monad doesn't let you magic up a random seed out of nowhere. Which is a consequence of the fact that unsafe operations aside, it *does* enforce referential transparency.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: I was trying to make that distinction.  But also the distinction that, given a random number, if you use it o permute an input list, the list's type doesn't change so details still leak out.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Couldn't you just import System.Random and then get a random number in the normal way: getStdRandom (randomR (1,100))? I haven't tested this out myself, but I don't see why it wouldn't work, given the apparent similarities between ST and the State monad.

Comment: Answered my own question: no, you can't. getStdRandom returns an IO action.

Comment: @Thus you need either `unsafePerformIO` or `unsafeIOtoST` which are both kind of ... unsafe ;)