# (Edited) How to get random number in Haskell without IO

Tags: haskell, unsafe-perform-io

I want to have a function that return different `stdGen` in each call without IO.
I've tried to use `unsafePerformIO`, as the following code.

```
import System.IO.Unsafe
import System.Random

myStdGen :: StdGen
myStdGen = unsafePerformIO getStdGen
```

But when I try to call `myStdGen` in ghci, I always get the same value. Have I abused `unsafePerformIO`? Or is there any other ways to reach my goal?

**EDIT**
Sorry, I think I should describe my question more precisely.

Actually, I'm implementing a variation of the treap data strutcure, which needs a special 'merge' operation. It relies on some randomness to guarentee amortized O(log n) expected time complexity.

I've tried to use a pair like `(Tree, StdGen)` to keep the random generator for each treap. When inserting a new data to the treap, I would use `random` to give random value to the new node, and then update my generator. But I've encountered a problem. I have a function called `empty` which will return an empty treap, and I used the function `myStdGen` above to get the random generator for this treap. However, if I have two empty treap, their `StdGen` would be the same. So after I inserted a data to both treap and when I want to merge them, their random value would be the same, too. Therefore, I lost the randomness which I relies on.

That's why I would like to have a somehow "global" random generator, which yields different `StdGen` for each call, so that each empty treap could have different `StdGen`.

Comment: Yes, this is an abuse.  If something returns different results with the same arguments it's not a (mathematical) function.  You can't have that.  You can do it in some monad, it doesn't have to be IO, but it has to keep some state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a good use of `unsafePerformIO`.

The reason you see the same number repeatedly in GHCi is that GHCi itself does not know that the value is impure, and so remembers the value from the last time you called it. You can type IO commands into the top level of GHCi, so you would expect to see a different value if you just type `getStdGen`. However, this won't work either, due to an obscure part of the way GHCi works involving not reverting top-level expressions. You can turn this of with `:set +r`:

```
> :set +r
> getStdGen
2144783736 1
> getStdGen
1026741422 1
```

Note that your impure function pretending to be pure will still not work.

```
> myStdGen
480142475 1
> myStdGen
480142475 1
> myStdGen
480142475 1
```

You really do not want to go down this route. `unsafePerformIO` is not supposed to be used this way, and nor is it a good idea at all. There are ways to get what you wanted (like `unsafePerformIO randomIO :: Int`) but they will not lead you to good things. Instead you should be doing calculations based on random numbers inside a random monad, and running that in the IO monad.

### Update

I see from your updatee why you wanted this in the first place.

There are many interesting thoughts on the problem of randomness within otherwise referentially transparent functions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237775/random-pivot-quicksort-in-haskell).

Despite the fact that some people advocate the use of `unsafePerformIO` in this case, it is still a bad idea for a number of reasons which are outlined in various parts of that page. In the end, if a function depends on a source of randomness it is best for that to be specified in it's type, and the easiest way to do that is put it in a random monad. This is still a pure function, just one that takes a generator when it is called. You can provide this generator by asking for a random one in the main `IO` routine.

A good example of how to use the random monad can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266765/how-to-use-monadrandom).

Comment: Interesting about `:set +r`. However, in my ghci-7.8.2, repeated `getStdGen` still gives always the same...

Comment: I'm still lingering in 7.6.3. Odd that this behaviour seems to have changed.

Answer (score 8):

> Do I abused `unsafePerformIO`

Heck yes! The "distinguishing features of a pure function" are

- No side-effects
- **Referentially transparent**, i.e. each subsequent eval of the result *must* yield the same.

There is in fact a way to achieve your "goal", but the idea is just wrong.

```
myStdGen :: () -> StdGen
myStdGen () = unsafePerformIO getStdGen
```

Because this is a (useless) function call instead of a [CAF](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/CAF), it'll evaluate the `IO` action at each call seperately.

Still, I think the compiler is pretty much free to optimise that away, so definitely don't rely on it.

**EDIT** upon trying I noticed that `getStdGen` itself always gives the same generator when used within a given process, so even if the above would use more reasonable types it would not work.

---

Note that correct use of pseudorandomness in algorithms etc. does *not* need IO everywhere – for instance you can manually seed your `StdGen`, but then properly propagate it with `split` etc.. A much nicer way to handle that is with a [randomness monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t:MonadRandom). The program as a whole will then always yield the same result, but internally have all different random numbers as needed to work usefully.

Alternatively, you can obtain a generator from IO, but still write your algorithm in a pure random monad rather than `IO`.

---

There's another way to obtain "randomness" in a completely pure algorithm: require the input to be [`Hashable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Hashable.html)! Then, you can effectively use any function argument as a random seed. This is a bit of a strange solution, but might work for your treap application (though I reckon some people would not classify it as a treap anymore, but as a special kind of hashmap).

Comment: I think you missed a `NOINLINE`. I also think this is something that actually *is* reasonable to want, but I don't think it's possible to guarantee that it will work right—although the results are the same up to `(==)`, I imagine the optimizer might be able to break things badly—if it decides to recalculate something rather than save it, all heck might break loose.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I'm not sure it if it would works. Because the purpose of the random key in treap is to prevent the worst case for a BST (a chain) which depends on the keys it contains. But the only input of the function is the key, so the random value will also depends on the keys inserted. However, in general cases, I think the worst case may not happen though. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you have abused `unsafePerformIO`.  There are very few valid reasons to use `unsafePerformIO`, such as when interfacing with a C library, and it's also used in the implementation of a handful of core libraries (I think `ST` being one of them).  In short, don't use `unsafePerformIO` unless you're really really sure of what you're doing.  It is not meant for generating random numbers.

Recall that functions in Haskell have to be pure, meaning that they only depend on their inputs.  This means that you can have a pure function that generates a "random" number, but that number is dependent on the random generator you pass to it, you could do something like

```
myStdGen :: StdGen
myStdGen = mkStdGen 42
```

Then you could do

```
randomInt :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
randomInt g = random
```

But then you must use the new `StdGen` returned from this function moving forward, or you will always get the same output from `randomInt`.

---

So you may be wondering, how do you cleanly generate random numbers without resorting to `IO`?  The answer is the `State` monad.  It looks similar to

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

And its monad instance looks like

```
instance Monad (State s) where
    return a = State $ \s -> (a, s)
    (State m) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = m s
                                        (State g)     = f a
                                    in g newState
```

It's a little confusing to look at the first time, but essentially all the state monad does is fancy function composition.  See [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) for a more detailed explanation.  What's important to note here is that the type of `s` does not change between steps, just the `a` parameter can change.

You'll notice that `s -> (a, s)` looks a lot like our function `StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)`, with `s ~ StdGen` and `a ~ Int`.  That means that if we did

```
randomIntS :: State StdGen Int
randomIntS = State randomInt
```

Then we could do

```
twoRandInts :: State StdGen (Int, Int)
twoRandInts = do
    a <- randomIntS
    b <- randomIntS
    return (a, b)
```

Then it can be run by supplying an initial state:

```
main = do
    g <- getStdGen
    print $ runState twoRandInts g
```

The `StdGen` still comes out of `IO`, but then all the logic itself occurs within the state monad purely.