# Haskell function with type IO Int -> Int, without using unsafePerformIO

Tags: haskell, io

I have a homework question asking me:

Can you write a Haskell function with type IO Int -> Int (without using unsafePerformIO)? If yes, give the function; if not, explain the reason.

I have tried to write such a function:

```
test :: IO Int -> Int
test a = do 
    x <- a
    return x
```

But this does not work. I have tried to make it work for a while, and I can't, so I gather that the answer to the question is no. But, I do not understand why it is not possible. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Hint: functions don't have to use all their arguments.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see how this helps me. By my understanding, my function has only one argument, and that is "IO Int". If I were to do:
    `test :: IO Int -> Int`
    `test a b = b`
I get the following error:
    `The equation(s) for ‘test’ have two arguments,
    but its type ‘IO Int -> Int’ has only one`

Comment: The function is allowed to use zero of its one arguments.  It doesn't have two arguments, so of course you can't write a pattern that takes two arguments.

Comment: Ah. I had thought of this, but dismissed it as trivial. Thinking again, this seems like the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: Another, perhaps more evil hint: all Haskell types are inhabited :3 Probably not the answer the question is looking for, though...

Comment: Based on your example code, here's another hint: in Haskell, `do`-blocks don't need to be terminated with a `while` statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two ways...

If you are happy with a constant function, use this:

```
test :: IO Int -> Int
test a = 42
```

Otherwise, you have to do the same thing that `unsafePerformIO` does (or more specifically `unsafeDupablePerformIO`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}

import GHC.Base (IO(..), realWorld#)

unIO (IO m) = case m realWorld# of (# _, r #) -> r

test :: IO Int -> Int
test a = (unIO a) + 1
```

Have fun...

Disclaimer: this is all really hacky ;)

Comment: you need to add a {-# NOINLINE unIO #-} for it to be equivalent to unsafeDupableIO

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27041993 .

Answer (score 4):

The only functions of type `IO Int -> Int` are uninteresting, since they must ignore their argument. that is, they must be equivalent to

```
n :: Int
n = ...

f :: IO Int -> Int
f _ = n
```

(Technically, there's also `` f x = x `seq` n ``, as @Keshav points out).

This is because there's no way to escape the IO monad (unlike most other monads). This is by design. Consider

```
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = fmap read getLine
```

which is a function which reads an integer from stdin. If we could write

```
n :: Int
n = f getInt
```

this would be an integer value which can "depend" on the IO action `getInt`... but must be pure, i.e. must do no IO at all. How can we use an IO action if we must do no IO at all? It turns out that we can not use it in any way.

The only way to do such operation meaningfully is to allow the programmer break the "purity" contract, which is the main thing behind Haskell. GHC gives the programmer a few "unsafe" operations if the programmer is bold enough to declare "trust me, I know what I am doing". One of them is "unsafePerformIO". Another is accessing the `realWorld#` low-level stuff in `GHC.*` modules (as @Michael shows above). Even the FFI can import a C function claiming it to be pure, essentially enabling the user to write their own `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: What about `f x = seq x n`?  That doesn't seem to be equivalent to `f _ = n`.  (Nor does `f = undefined`, for what it's worth, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: @KeshavKini: it's pretty much equivalent, in that the result of `seq x n` is either a constant `n` or bottom.  For that matter, `f _ = undefined` is also pretty much equivalent.

Comment: @JohnL: My point was that if `f x = seq x n`, then the value of `f x` depends on what `x` is, whereas a function defined as `f _ = n` for some `n :: Int` cannot depend on anything about its argument.  `f = undefined` also differs from all functions defined as `f _ = n` for some `n :: Int`, because in the latter case, f itself (unapplied) normalizes, whereas `undefined` does not.

Yet `f x = seq x n` and `f = undefined` are both valid definitions for the type signature `f :: IO Int -> Int`, so it seems incorrect to say that all functions of type `IO Int -> Int` must be equivalent to `f _ = n`.

Comment: @KeshavKini I somehow agree, but the distinction between `undefined` and `\_->undefined` is not very significant, and relevant only when `seq` is involved. If we want to be very picky `undefined` is also different from `error "a"`. We could also consider the infinite different values `error "some string"`. Then why not including expressions involving `trace`?

Comment: About the FFI "*essentially enabling the user to write their own `unsafePerformIO`*" - if only the FFI was that capable: then `unsafePerformIO` would not be needed as a primitive definition...